# AppCompatActivity cannot be resolved to a type in eclipse

Tags: android

I am using version 5.0.1 api level 21.I have added appcompat library in project properties.But I am getting `compile error:` AppCompatActivity cannot be resolved to a type.

**RegisterActivity.java:**

```
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;

public class RegisterDevice extends AsyncTask<String, String, String>{

    AppCompatActivity _activity;

    public RegisterDevice(AppCompatActivity _activity) {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        this._activity = _activity;
    }
}
```

**res/values/themes.xml:**

error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'buttonStyle'.

```
<resources xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <style name="WT_DEFAULT_THEME" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light">
        <!-- All customizations that are NOT specific to a particular API-level can go here. -->
    .......
    .......
        <item name="buttonStyle">@style/WT_DEFAULT_BUTTON</item>
    </style>
```

Right Click of project->Properties ->Android :

[image]

I am not sure why this error occurred still.I had created new project.Appcompat library was supported for newly created projects.But in this project it is not supported.

**Edit:**

[image]

Comment: Did you define appcompat lib in your build.gradle file?

Comment: @Archinamon I am using eclipse

Comment: why don't you switch to android studio . It is the official IDE and far more easier than eclipse

Comment: I think you should add design library

Comment: I am having the same problem except I am linking to `androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity`. My app compiles from the command line, but I can't find the necessary libraries to link to in Eclipse.

Answer (score 1):

please find this below links for proper dependencies into your project.

[Cannot resolve symbol 'AppCompatActivity'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29199891/cannot-resolve-symbol-appcompatactivity)

[AppCompatActivity cannot be resolved to a type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32913702/appcompatactivity-cannot-be-resolved-to-a-type)

Hope this will help..!!!

Comment: Please add some code from these links that can  be helpful here.